# Dynamically execute several remove_action() calls based on a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array, foreach

I'm trying dynamically execute a series of `remove_action()` function calls in my Wordpress application based on a config array with a specific structure.

Hard-coded, the correct execution would be:

```
remove_action('genesis_after_header', 'genesis_do_nav');
remove_action('genesis_after_header', 'genesis_do_subnav');
remove_action('genesis_site_title', 'genesis_seo_site_title', 5);
```

I want to perform the same execution based on a multidimensional array like this:

```
$config = array(
    'remove_actions' => [
        'genesis_after_header' => [
            'genesis_do_nav',
            'genesis_do_subnav'
        ],
        'genesis_site_title' => [
            'genesis_seo_site_title' => 5
        ],
    ],
);
```

Here is my attempt to iterate the config array to execute the three `remove_action()` calls:

```
foreach ($config as $hook => $functions) {
    foreach ($functions as $function => $priority) {
        if (! is_null($priority)) {
            remove_action($hook, $function);
        } else {
            remove_action($hook, $function, $priority);
        }
    }
}
```

This isn't correctly accessing the values as intended.

Comment: Does this get you closer to what you need? https://3v4l.org/CacgE

Comment: yes..  but only with 3 parameter. $hook , $timing, $priority

Comment: Then you want it like this? https://3v4l.org/ljpNd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust your config structure so that `$function` always comes from a key and its value (which may be `null`) will be the `$priority`.

```
$config = [
    'remove_actions' => [
        'genesis_after_header' => [
            'genesis_do_nav' => null,
            'genesis_do_subnav' => null,
        ],
        'genesis_site_title' => [
            'genesis_seo_site_title' => 5
        ],
    ],
];
```

When accessing the data, the first loop must access `$config['remove_actions']`. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/ljpNd)

```
foreach ($config['remove_actions'] as $hook => $functions) {
    foreach ($functions as $function => $priority) {
        if (is_null($priority)) {
            remove_action($hook, $function);
        } else {
            remove_action($hook, $function, $priority);
        }
    }
}
```